# Show another element if current input was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to show one element if current input was changed.

```
$('.type_number').change(function() {
  $(this)
  $('.check-update').css('display', 'block')
})
```

```html
<input class="type_number" type="number" name="amount" value="{{ product.amount }}">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ product.product.id }}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-link check-update">
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</button>
```

How to say jquery if current was changed show another element

This creates a difficulty for me and besides I can not figure out how to do it. Please explain me if someone knows about it

Comment: can you add your html too ?

Comment: And make it as snippet or fiddle

Comment: $('.check-update').show()

Comment: What is `$(this)` for? Remove it.

Comment: no it just for understanding

Comment: $('your input field here').on('change', function(){ $(this).closest('parentElementHere').find('WhateverElementHere').show(); });  - this is just for showing, that you can go up and down the dom tree as you like.

Comment: Thank you Stender) Good commented :) It works

Comment: I've adjusted my code. Is that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want I guess. It's in pure `Javascript`

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#my-text-box');

var messages = document.querySelector('#messages');

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
   messages.style.display = 'block'
});
```

```html
<input id="my-text-box" /> 

<div id="messages" style="display: none">I was hidden First</div>
```

It's just a demo to give you an idea of how to get your thing working

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to show div when someone starts typing in it. In that case you should use `keypress` event. Like this:

```js
$('.type_number').keypress(function() {
    $('.check-update').show();
    $('input').attr('type', 'text'); 
});
```

```css
.check-update {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input class='type_number' type="text">
  <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ product.product.id }}">
  <div class='check-update'>Div when somebody starts typing</div>
```

EDIT: OP wants to remove type hidden from input. I've adjusted the code, so that every hidden input will show when user starts to type.

Comment: I can have two and three such elements and when current input will change i should show icon. If i will use this code it will work for all inputs

Comment: You can add same class to all input elements that you want hidden and set css of that class to display:none that this will work on all hidden inputs. Also remove type hidden from your input if you want to do it this way.

Comment: I do not create inputs. They are generating as django template. There only one input :)

Comment: I've adjusted code. Now every input will show when someone starts typing. Is that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, if input element value is not empty and changed other than "myname", it shows the label with value "bob".

html

```
<input id = "type_number" type = "text" value="myname"/>
<label id = "check-update" style="display:none;">bob</label>
```

jQuery

```
$("#type_number").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    if($("#type_number").val() !== "" && $("#type_number").val() !== "myname")
        $("#check-update").css("display", "block");
   else 
        $("#check-update").css("display", "none");
});
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/harshen/u4tj58mf/)

Answer (score -1):

#### Maybe you're searching this:

```js
$('.type_number').change(function () {
      
         if($(this).val() < 1 ) {
          $('.check-update i').addClass('fa-remove');
          $('.check-update i').removeClass('fa-check');
         } else {
            $('.check-update i').addClass('fa-check');
             $('.check-update i').removeClass('fa-remove');
        }
     });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="type_number" type="number" name="amount" value="{{ product.amount }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ product.product.id }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link check-update"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
```